# Material DateTimePicker onChange Typescript mismatch error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a following React + Material DatePicker code, reproduced literally [from the respective documentation](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage).

```
let App: React.FC = () => {

const [dateStart, handleDateStart] = useState(new Date());
const [dateEnd, handleDateEnd] = useState(new Date());

return (
    // Pickers from Material https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <DateTimePicker value={dateStart} onChange={handleDateStart}/>
        <DateTimePicker value={dateEnd} onChange={handleDateEnd}/>)
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>);

};
```

However, I write in TypeScript and it complains on the **onChange** bits:

```
Error:(28, 47) TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>' is not assignable to type '(date: MaterialUiPickersDate) => void'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'date' are incompatible.
 Type 'MaterialUiPickersDate' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.
 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.
```

TsConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I am new to React and Material, how can I avoid this error?

Comment: whats your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @demkovych I have added it to the question.

Comment: check this: https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/

Comment: No, it does not help.

Comment: I think it uses moment under the hood. Did you try: `useState(momen(new Date()))`

Comment: same. actually it allows different libraries

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that datepicker can return `null` as well (in case value is empty)

Working example:

```
const [date, setDate] = React.useState<Date | null>(new Date());

return (
  <DatePicker
    value={date} 
    onChange={newDate => setDate(newDate)} 
  />
)
```

Comment: Many thanks, glad to see the author here :) I would suggest adding this to the official documentation, as many people use TypeScript.

Comment: Seeking help. This didn't work for me. I'm getting:`Argument of type 'MaterialUiPickersDate' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date | null>'.
  Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date | null>'.
    Type 'Moment' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 35 more.`

Comment: So you need to change Date to Moment and it will work

Comment: Where does the type Moment come from? @DmitriyKovalenko

Answer (score 4):

Import MaterialUiPickersDate

```
import { MaterialUiPickersDate } from '@material-ui/pickers/typings/date';
```

Working Example

```
import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { MaterialUiPickersDate } from '@material-ui/pickers/typings/date';

interface IDateTimePickerComponent {
    label: string;
}

function DateTimePickerComponent({ label }: IDateTimePickerComponent) {
    const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] =
        useState<MaterialUiPickersDate | null>(new Date());

    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <DateTimePicker
                disablePast
                label={label}
                value={selectedDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
            />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
}

export default DateTimePickerComponent;
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it helped to set my type to this:

```
startsAt: Date | Moment | null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `useState<Date>(new Date())` to prevent error check type of typescript

Comment: No, it does not help